# Add BCC to appointment on button click

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a custom form in my appointment in which I have a CommandButton and a BCC field.

When the user press my commandButton, I want to add a mail to my BCC field.

Currently I have the following:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set test = Item.Recipients.Add('alice@yahoo.com')
    test = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
    Item.Recipients.ResolveAll();
End Sub
```

I have tried a couple of different things, without any luck.

Thus far, I have only managed to add a standard Recipient, I.e.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set oMsg = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
With oMsg 
    .Recipients.Add("test")
End With
```

End Sub

But it seems to be more convoluted to add a BCC mail

Therefore, how do I add a mail to my BCC field on commandbutton click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the `Item.Recipients.ResolveAll()` method did not work. Therefore, I skipped writing to a variable, and instead concatenated the type to `.Recipients.Add()`.

```
Function CommandButton1_Click()
    Set oMsg = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 

    With oMsg 
            .Recipients.Add(Mail).Type = 3
    End With
End Function
```

The following works, and can be repeated with multiple recipients.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax to set the `Type` property of the recipient, and then resolve all.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set test = Item.Recipients.Add("alice@yahoo.com")
    test.Type = olBCC
    Item.Recipients.ResolveAll()
End Sub
```

In your method you're trying to set the `Item` as an integer (cast from the BCC type), instead of setting the `Type` property OF the `Item`

Comment: hmm, first line gives me a 'syntax error'.. The debugger is not giving alot of information

Comment: Do you have the library reference to `Outlook Object Library`

Comment: Oh wait, there's `;` semi-colons and `'` quotes instead of `"` because the original code was from a `c#` snippet it seems. I got rid of them. Try again!

Comment: That makes sense! It doesnt give me any syntax error now, but the mail is not added. Nothing really happens :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to modify the `Recipients` collection of the item:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim recip as Outlook.Recipient
    Set recip = Item.Recipients.Add('alice@yahoo.com')
    recip.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
    Item.Recipients.ResolveAll();
End Sub
```

Note, the MeetingItem recipient can be one of the following `OlMeetingRecipientType` constants: `olOptional`, `olOrganizer`, `olRequired`, or `olResource`.

Most probably you will have to create a new MailItem and send it out separately as BCC.